# Determine http or https request in IIS Logs

Tags: http, iis, logging, https

I'm going through my IIS logs. I want to see if a request was sent with http or https protocol. How do I see that in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Boolean server variable {HTTPS}.You could add a custom server variable field for that.

If the field is false, it means the request was sent via http. if the field is true, then we would know the request is come from https.

I think it is hard to display http or https in IIS log directly.
[image]

Comment: I don't have access to add a custom variable. I was hoping there was an out of the box way to do it but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Rafi. This is not a custom variable but a custom IIS log field. You only have to enable that in IIS log without adding any custom variable. {HTTPS} is just a default request variable.